# Clicking on the Menu Item

Tags: c#, menu, click, watin

I am trying to automate CRM application. I have a scenario where i should click on a Menu and then click on the list item , which should open another window. I was able to get to the list item and click it and i can see on the browser clicking but does not open the window, no event is being fired. Here is how the html looks when i looked thru the IE developer tools .

Text - Test1
Here is the code that performs the click

```
IE activity = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("testpage"));

List newList = activity.List(Find.ById("mnuaction"));

newList.Click();

ElementCollection ec = newList.ElementsWithTag("li");

ec[4].Click();
```

If any one has done any coding around CRM test automation could you please enlighten me on this topic

Answer (score 0):

Try to fire the event by your self:

```
browser.Eval(string.Format("$('#{0},.{0}').change();", "elementId/elementClass"));
```

This JS dealing with element "Class" or "Id"